# Manga where the mc is transported in another world but he was already really good at fighting

Tags: story-identification, manga

As soon as he was transported to the other world, the magician said something about putting a brand on him. When he hears that, he attacks them and then uses another soldier's armor, he acts as a soldier then they send him to the infirmary, where he starts a fire and escapes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or locations, or anything distinctive about the artwork?

Answer (score 3):

This is *[Record of Wortenia War](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/record-of-wortenia-war)*, aka *Wortenia Senki*. It is licensed by [J-Novel Club](https://j-novel.club/series/record-of-wortenia-war-manga).

> Ryoma Mikoshiba, **an ordinary high-schooler adept at martial arts, one day finds himself summoned to another world**. The ones who summoned him, the O’ltormea Empire, cite the fact that 'when those summoned kill another living being, they can absorb a fraction of their strength and make it their own' as their reason. But upon learning the empire uses those they summon to strengthen themselves by foul means, Ryoma is consumed by hatred and slays an important member of the O’ltormean court. ...

As mentioned in the synopsis, the protagonist is summoned to another world but is already a skilled fighter, due to being trained by his grandfather. When he is summoned, he kills the people responsible for the summoning, and wears the armor of one of the dead soldiers.

[image: Protagonist in soldier armor]

Once in the infirmary, he sets it on fire as a distraction and escapes.

[image]